Are questions about the writings of occultists on-topic?
Are questions about occult philosophical texts (e.g. the Corpus Hermeticum or Crowley's The Book of the Law) on-topic? I don't believe there's an 'esoterica', and while some aspects of the occult would be more suited for a particular religion SE (Judaism SE has a kabbalah tag) and some alchemical things might be suited for history of science I think most of them don't have a better place to be answered.
The line between "serious philosophy" and occultism is obviously blurry (see: neoplatonism) and some philosophers reference esoterica a lot, so asking questions about it might help contextualize their writings.
That said, it also feels like that opens the door to a lot of low-quality questions. "What did  mean by this quote" may be intentionally vague or impossible to answer, and that's before even getting into "bad" questions about occult philosophy. ("In hermetic philosophy, how can I turn myself into a vampire?" or "in Discordian philosophy...")
SEP, for comparison, has articles on ancient occultism (in the contexts of ancient/medieval/Renaissance philosophers) but not articles on modern occultists.
Related: Can we remove "theology" from the scope of philosophy.SE?

Literature and skeptics can be candidate sites, depending on the question. Else I think such books are not automatically on-topic and thus it would depend on the question.

Questions about the Bible is off topic. But related philosophical questions are on topic to some degree, like philosophical arguments supporting or refuting Christianity. I'd suggest roughly the same principle here, but I wouldn't be able to be more specific than that for this specific domain.

The question has to be about philosophy. A question about the writings of an occultist is not necessarily in or out of scope; what will matter is whether it is about philosophy. I can imagine many questions about occultist writings that would be off-topic and many that would be on-topic.

I guess I think the boundary of "philosophy" gets blurred right. The metaphysics of hermetic philosophy isn't easily distinguished from the magical or religious aspects.

Conflicted on this...
On the one hand I am very interested in what may be called off-beat philosophy/philosophers.
This is would go a little toward countering the Christian-Antichristian (ie western) bias that by default obtains out here.
On the other, it can quickly go down a rabbits hole of what you call low quality questions. And then get swamped by nonsense.

From https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=occult

1530s, "secret, not divulged," from French occulte and directly from Latin occultus "hidden, concealed, secret," past participle of occulere "cover over, conceal," from assimilated form of ob "over" (see ob-) + a verb related to celare "to hide" (from PIE root *kel- (1) "to cover, conceal, save"). Meaning "not apprehended by the mind, beyond the range of understanding" is from 1540s. The association with the supernatural sciences (magic, alchemy, astrology, etc.) dates from 1630s. A verb occult "to keep secret, conceal" (c.1500, from Latin occultare) is obsolete. (emphasis mine)

You ask:

Are questions about the writings of occultists on-topic?

No topic is off topic if it's philosophically inclined. Of course, how to take inclination and make that a meaningful metric of semantic concept hinges, to some extent, on linking the discourse to a recognized philosophy-of. According to WP:

The occult (from Latin: occultus, lit. 'hidden' or 'secret') is a category of esoteric or supernatural beliefs and practices which generally fall outside the scope of organized religion and science, encompassing phenomena involving a 'hidden' or 'secret' agency, such as magic and mysticism.

So, any question which invokes questions of the occult is just as fair game as religion or science when it is in regards to a philosophical aspect of the topic such as belief (the epistemological), taxonomy (the ontological), or the ultimate nature of reality and experience (the metaphysical). While the SEP and the IEP don't have an article on it (though I'd be curious if it were on their want-lists), the REP does at https://www.rep.routledge.com/articles/thematic/magic/v-1. The abstract:

Magic is the art of influencing the workings of nature through occult powers. It can be found in most societies throughout history. It is often defined by contrast with other subjects, such as science, rationality and religion. Practitioners of magic might fashion themselves as necromancers, magi or natural philosophers; and accused practitioners were often labelled as sorcerers, heretics or witches. Concentrated, though at times incoherent, expositions of what we might call the epistemology of magic reached their height in European philosophy in late antiquity in the writings of Plotinus, Porphyry and Proclus; this interest was rekindled in the Renaissance in the writings of Agrippa, Pico, Ficino and others in what is often described as the Hermetic or Occultist tradition. Whether magic worked according to natural, demonic or divine forces was debated, and during the Renaissance demonology shifted from a theological to a natural philosophical pursuit. In the Middle Ages explaining how magic worked was a concern of theologians; in the Renaissance it was a concern of natural philosophers and physicians; and in the modern period it is a concern of anthropologists and historians. Magic has always been associated with trickery and danger, and with knowledge and power. (emphasis mine)

So, instead of a shallow dive into philosophy (does it mention Socrates? did Kant write about it? is it in my introductory gloss of philosophy?), it's fair to demonstrate a number of traditionally defensible "philosophically on-topic topics" are interwoven. After all, though 'occult' doesn't have an article in the SEP or IEP, the word is pervasive in a number of articles:

Greek philosophers of antiquity, such as Plotinus (SEP) and Porphyry (SEP), certainly topics like theurgy and thaumaturgy would be an interest.
Outside of the West, religion, magic, and philosophy in pre-modern times was experienced as all three. Religious Taoism (SEP) and Taoist medicine (SEP) are a fascinating blend of pseudo-science, magic, divination, religious, and philosophical thinking and practice.
While modern and post-modern science are very distinct from pseudo-scientific practices given the gains in philosophy of science by a rather global community of thinkers, during the Renaissance, Aufklärung, and Rinascimento (SEP), thinkers such as Newton and others certainly had an interest in alchemy and the occult. Sorting out science and pseudoscience took hundreds of years.
From the Routledge article, we can see that the concept of magic was subsequently studied by theologians, naturalists, and modern social scientists. Thus, modern thinkers in the philosophy of science should certainly have a strong interest in how the supernatural, occult, and magical relate to the science/pseudoscience dichotomy (SEP) and affect belief.
And this interest of the relationship between the occult, religion, and science goes back to the original self-claimed positivist himself, Comte, who had his Law of Three Stages (Britannica.com).

So, yes, the supernatural, the occult, and the magical absolutely can be discussed at PhilSE, provided they do it by appealing to a philosophical mode of speech. Does the question relate to the philosophy of science? religion? social science? history of philosophy? beliefs of a philosopher? Does it figure into metaphilosophical discourse or meta-ethical theory? Is it pertinent to sussing out conceptual development of supernaturalism or related to the origins of naturalistic thinking during the separation of natural philosophy from Scholastic thought? If so, then yes.

Surprised that hadn't come up before.
